# in vs at + gerund

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

Consider the following examples:

1. Would you be interested *in* buying a ticket
2. Jerry is very good *at* playing drums

The first sentence uses '*in*' before the gerund while the second one uses '*at*'. Why would that happen? Are there some patterns that we could use to apply '*in*' and '*at*' before the gerund. Is it wrong if I replace *in* with *at* in the second example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either preposition is part of the verb. One is interested *in* something or good *at* something.

Being good *in* something doesn't sound *too* weird to me, but it does invoke a thought of cooking..

Comment: Hi , Thanks, you mean 'part of the verb' means that 'in playing' is a single unit of word? And what you mean by 'thought of cooking'

Comment: Tthe verbs are *to be interested in sth.* and *to be good at sth.*, it has nothing to do with the gerund. To me, *to be good in sth.* sounds like it would make a good ingredient in a soup (Thus invoking thoughts of cooking).